# Has anyone been able to run HTTP in a WebView?

Tags: android, http, android-webview

Has anyone been able to run http in WebView with Android Studio? i try to have acces local but dosnt work with http only https.

Comment: What version of Android are you using? HTTP is blocked by default on Android 9.0.

Comment: Android studio 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android 9 (I believe), clear-text (http) is not permitted by default.

Please see this answer:
[WebView is not loading page in Android 9.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594637/webview-is-not-loading-page-in-android-9-0)