# WebView local files is not loading page in Android 9.0?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-9.0-pie

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
```

On older versions, webview for local files is working fine, but when I decided to test on android 9 It gives a blank page.

I have tried [WebView is not loading page in Android 9.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594637/webview-is-not-loading-page-in-android-9-0) these solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting below code in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    ...
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
</application>
```

> What it does

It allows your app to access non secure(Non-Https) based url. See [Security Config](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

From Documentation

> Note: The guidance in this section applies only to apps that target
>   Android 8.1 (API level 27) or lower. Starting with Android 9 (API
>   level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

**EDIT**

```
try {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream stream = assetManager.open("html/index.html");
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        total.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, total.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
} catch (Exception xxx) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error loading html/index.html", xxx);
}
```

Comment: I tried but it's not working in my case .I'm using the local files "file:///android_asset/html/index.html"

Comment: no error in logcat Only it shows a white blank page.

Comment: You can also use `webView.loadData(total.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8")` instead of `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, total.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null)`