# Webpage not available, WebView Android

Tags: java, android, android-webview

```
WebView WebDimrah;
WebSettings WebSettingDimrah;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    WebDimrah  = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView1);
    WebSettingDimrah  = WebDimrah.getSettings() ;

    WebDimrah.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebDimrah.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebDimrah.loadUrl("https://facebook.com");
```

Hello, I have problem, I have a home work to make web view with android studio, and I type url facebook, than I run it, but it's just like that

[image]

I have a permission on my manifest, but in my avd still Webpage Not available

Logcat:

````
11-17 19:16:06.535 5829-5829/com.dimrahwebkit E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
11-17 19:16:06.535 5829-5829/com.dimrahwebkit E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets
11-17 19:16:06.545 5829-5829/com.dimrahwebkit E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets
11-17 19:16:06.545 5829-5829/com.dimrahwebkit E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.removeOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
11-17 19:16:06.545 5829-5829/com.dimrahwebkit E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$1', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener
11-17 19:16:06.585 5829-5829/com.dimrahwebkit E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
11-17 19:16:06.975 5829-5829/com.dimrahwebkit E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
11-17 19:16:06.975 5829-5829/com.dimrahwebkit E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
11-17 19:16:06.975 5829-5829/com.dimrahwebkit E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
11-17 19:16:07.255 5829-5829/com.dimrahwebkit E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
11-17 19:16:07.255 5829-5829/com.dimrahwebkit E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
11-17 19:16:07.255 5829-5829/com.dimrahwebkit E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
11-17 19:16:07.255 5829-5829/com.dimrahwebkit E/EGL_emulation: tid 5829: eglSurfaceAttrib(1199): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `override` the `onReceivedSslError()` method of the `WebViewClient` for the webpage to display. Here is what your code should look like :

```
private WebView WebDimrah;
private WebSettings WebSettingDimrah;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


WebDimrah  = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView1);
WebSettingDimrah  = WebDimrah.getSettings() ;
WebDimrah.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

WebDimrah.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {

handler.proceed();

      }
   });
 WebDimrah.loadUrl("https://facebook.com");

}
```

Also, in your `Android.xml` file (manifest) add this line: 
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` inside the ... tag.

Comment: sorry but now i had a blank page

Comment: @DimasRahmadian i'll add some code to the one above. Try it again.

Comment: @DimasRahmadian try the above code. Also I believe you have added the necessary permissions to your manifest file i.e `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: I have added it, but it's still blank

Comment: @DimasRahmadian can you show a copy of your Logcat ?

Comment: @DimasRahmadian i just figured out the issue. The webpage would display on android versions lower than API 29. It displays on API 28 and lower.

Comment: Honestly it's my new experience, and now what should i do sir?

Comment: @DimasRahmadian, if what Mayokun said is true, then you might want to check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594637/webview-is-not-loading-page-in-android-9-0

Comment: @DimasRahmadian the newly edited code would work on Android 9 (API Level 28) and below. The issue is for Android Q (API Level 29) which I have opened an issue for :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901080/android-q-api-level-29-doesnt-load-https-websites-gives-error-neterr-acc

Comment: @DimasRahmadian add this `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your `Android.xml` file inside the <application>....</application> tag. The code above works fine now.

Comment: @Mayokun thankyou sir, my problem has been solved, you're a good person. thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @Whales thanks for your help too, and sorry for my bad english