# Android Q (API level 29) doesn't load HTTPS websites. Gives error: (net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-webview, android-10.0

I was trying fix an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58899869/webpage-not-available-webview-android/58900009#58900009) here on Stackoverflow as the person was trying to make use of `WebView` to load Facebook's website "https://facebook.com/" but couldn't get it done. I looked at the code and saw that the `onReceivedSslError()` method was not overridden. I overrode it and tested it out myself on Android emulators running Android 9 (API level 28) and lower and it worked **even without adding the `cleartextTrafficPermitted`** however, on testing on Android Q (API level 29), I was getting this error:

> net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

[image]

Here is a copy of the `onCreate` method:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView webDimrah = findViewById(R.id.WebView1);
        WebSettings webSettingDimrah = webDimrah.getSettings();
        webSettingDimrah.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webDimrah.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
                handler.proceed();
            }

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return true;
            }
        });
        webDimrah.loadUrl("https://facebook.com/");

    }
```

*Internet permission has been added to the manifest file*. Any suggestions on how to solve this would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your manifest make sure to add         `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Android 6.0 introduced the useCleartextTraffic attribute under application element in android manifest. The default value in Android P is “false”. Setting this to true indicates that the app intends to use clear network traffic.

Comment: This setting seems to have solved the problem, but the question here is HTTPS website, I think setting clearTextTraffic would allow HTTP connections, whereas HTTPS is encrypted hence I guess clearText setting not meant for HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

You have to use android:usesCleartextTraffic in you manifest.

This flag is ignored on Android 7.0 (API level 24) and above if an Android Network Security Config is present.

Please check the below explanation from Developer site for more details.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic